# JMeter not recording for .NET application

Tags: .net, performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

My application is developed in .NET, It has one scenario where after 4 steps(Pages) registration will happen. Jmeter is not recording the last step, where as it is able to record the first three steps.

Step 1. Fill the form click on next 
Step 2 Input some data and click on next 
Step 3. Upload some document and click next 
Step 4. Fill the last page and click on "Submit" button

After 4th step, one new pop-up window will display having registration number

If I am trying to do the same without using JMeter, application is behaving ok. Jmeter version is 2.9

Answer (score 0):

You should first upgrade to jmeter 2.11.

If it still does not work, in recorder switch to java implementation instead of HttpClient.